# Split dataset in batches to save memory

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've got some tf.Dataset with too much elements to fit into memory.
Currently, I fetch some sample indices and fetch these indices as one batch with dataset.map().

Now I'd like to split this into batches, perform an operation and sum up the results.

I'd need something like a map-reduce function with configurable batch size.
How do I solve this with Tensorflow?

Comment: Did you try dataset.batch()? Also shedding some light on the code you've used already, might help. Just in case you've missed, [here's](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance) the link for input-pipeline enhancement in tensorflow. Check if this helps.

Comment: I solved it now using a tf.while_loop and an initializable iterator.
The problem is that iterators do not have a `has_next()` method, so I have to include index variables in all datasets.

That's the only way it works, but it's very ugly.